# Input some word will cause the Qt application program crash

Tags: qt

I am Chinese.

I downloaded the Qt5.2 a few days ago.
I use the QLineEdit in the program. When I switch to the Chinese input methods, and input “?” (Question mark).
The program crash! 
What’s more, I use the Qt Creator, sometims, it would crash too.

Does it a bug? Or how could I correct it?

Comment: Hi, I created a new project a few minites ago. And only add a QLineEdit in it. When I switch to the Chinese input methods, and input “?” (Question mark). It crashed too.

Comment: Can you provide some backtrace?

Comment: Run it in a debugger, show the code

Comment: The OS is Win xp. The dubug says the error is at :> qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsKeyMapper::updatePossibleKeyCodes(unsigned char * kbdBuffer=0x0013d9d0, unsigned int scancode=0, unsigned int vk_key=65311)  行 584 + 0x12 字节

Comment: Does it work on Linux or Windows 7? Could you please provide the complete backtrace in your question?

Comment: I tried many times. I found maybe it is machine problem. I used Qt5.2 in other computer and it worked fine! But it can't work in my computer and can't work in the OS which install in virtualbox. It showed debug Error: File: global\qglobal.cpp; line:2096; ASSERT:"vk > 0 & vk < 256" in file qwindowskeymapper.cpp line 486. Then I tried Qt5.1.1 and it worked fine in my computer.